# Snort generates an alert that is empty

Tags: snort

I am working with commands that have already been tested to work but they aren't working now.

This is my config file:

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg: "/etc/passwd Payload Found"; content: "/etc/passwd/"; sid: 69;)
```

It works. It generates an alert.

I use snort to put the alert file into a log directory

```
snort -r FRAG3z.pcap -c frag3.conf -dev -l log -d -q
```

I execute the snort command, and I go into the log directory and my alert is there. I then open the alert and is completely empty. Anyone got any ideas.

Comment: *i am working with commands that having already been tested to work but they aren't working* - if it worked before and is not working now you are probably doing something different. Since it is unknown to use what changed it is hard to tell what the cause of your problem is. And the current information do not make it possible to reproduce your problem too.

Comment: My obvious question is if you have tried any other configs regarding the content of snort logs. Snort can output many different things, and you might not have specified what you want to output.